# 'Step into' debugging in PowerShell scripts not working anymore

Tags: powershell, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm running VS Code 1.32.3 with PowerShell Extension 1.11.0.

When debugging PowerShell scripts I always used "Step into" (F11 key) to step through the code and into functions called by the main script.
VS Code then automatically opened the .ps1 file containing the function und I could continue debugging the function with the F11 key.

That is not working anymore. VS code is not stepping into the function, instead it remains in the calling main script. The only way to step into the function is to click on the function name in the Call Stack window of VS Code. Now I can see the line of code which is currentliy processed, but after pressing the F11 key again VS code jumps back to the calling script window.

I cannot find any setting that would change that behaviour. Have there been changes in the debugging code with one of the recent releases?

I couldn't find anything in the release notes.

Comment: I'd write an issue on the powershell extension github page.  This isn't really the place for this question.

Comment: https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues

Comment: Just saw that someone else also reported this issue.
https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/1803